# How to add an endorsing peer in hyperledger fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

What steps are required in order to add an endorsing peer to a blockchain network (in hyperledger-fabric)? What about promoting a committing peer in an endorsing one?
Should I just alter files `crypto-config.yaml` and `configtx.yaml` by adding the new peer?

I am using the `fabcar` example from the `fabric-samples` repo (https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples), so should I change the `docker-compose(-cli).yaml` also? When starting the network with `startFabric.sh` script, should I just install chaincode on the new peers, or are other steps requires also?

I tried it with just installing a chaincode on the new peers, however I got an error stating that "... Consortium was not met when instantiating the chaincode ..."

**Edit:**

I was able to install the chaincode on all four peers and instantiate it on the channel. Initial non-query transaction is successful and another one after it. However, after the first two transactions I get:

> Failed to submit transaction createInquiry: Error: Peer localhost:8051 has rejected transaction "e8a83c12bfbcae97c7a3f2baaad7735fe8b44195a0ce252a3533a7b4a2a8103b" with code "ENDORSEMENT_POLICY_FAILURE"

Answer (score 0):

can you stop, remove and kill containers and try once again to instantiate.

Comment: I have a script for it, named `purge.sh` that removes all the containers, chaincode iamges and volumes.